# ServiceStack and non-database objects

Tags: c#, servicestack, dto

I'm a C# coder with a (Windows) sysadmin background.  I've been looking at the various service frameworks in order to create a unified REST-API for various infrastructure components (windows management, hardware management, etc.).  I've settled on using ServiceStack as my framework for this, but have a question on how to manage my DTOs.  Most of the time my source data is from non-database objects, which include:

- Other web services (usually SOAP based).  I usually bring these in via "Add Web Reference" (most, but not all, are asmx).
- .NET Objects (usually WMI/WinRM/PowerShell [System.Management], or Active Directory [System.DirectoryServices])...
- In some unfortunate cases, raw text output I get as a result of invoking a command (via ssh or cmd).

In all of these cases, I will have to call some sort of Save() method to update properties.  In addition, there might be some non-CRUD methods I would like to expose to the REST service.  Usually I don't need everything from the source data (for example, in the case of web service data, I'm only interested in boxing up certain properties and methods of a particular proxy class).  My understanding is that my DTOs should be clean and not have any dependencies.  Since I don't believe I have an ORM I can use, what design pattern should I use to map my data to a DTO?

Apologies if I'm misusing any terminology here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a variety of backend services and data sources, I think it would be hard to use anything highly structured like a framework to map your data to DTOs. I would keep it simple:

[Keep your DTO classes separate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368257/servicestack-new-service-side-by-side-asp-net-mvc-website/15369736#15369736) from any of your backend classes. Generally resist the temptation to try to reuse code, use inheritance, etc., in your DTOs (though sometimes I find it useful to declare interfaces for the DTOs to implement). This will keep the interface of your your ServiceStack service clean and independent of backend details.

There are some extension methods available in ServiceStack to easily map properties between two classes: `TranslateTo`, `PopulateWith`, `PopulateWithNonDefaultValues`, etc. The link above mentions these. The trick is that while your DTO classes should not be subclasses of, or directly reusing your backend classes, you will find it convenient to have the property names match up if you want to use these mapping methods.

Keep your ServiceStack service classes simple; their primary responsibility should be translating between DTO classes and lower level model classes, and making one or two method calls on business logic classes to do the actual work.

It sounds like it would be useful for the highest level of your business layer--the classes that your ServiceStack services interact with--to present a clean interface that abstracts away the details about the source and format of a given type of data. So you may want three layers of model classes. From top to bottom: DTOs, business layer POCO classes, and framework-specific classes for specific backend services like web reference generated code or whatever.

I think that's about all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you define DTOs that meet the requirements of your API, and then have a 'business logic' layer that mediates between the actual objects and your DTOs.

Your ServiceStack services will have a dependency on both the DTO definitions and the business logic layer, and the business logic layer will have a dependency on the DTO definitions and the real-world object definitions.  In effect, your REST services and DTOs will act as a facade over the real-world APIs.

Comment: @esker said it better (and faster) than I could.  What he said.