# ServiceStack sessions doesn't work when using JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo

Tags: c#, session, serialization, servicestack

In the AppHost I'm setting `JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo=true;` to prevent the type being serialized into the response (I'm using anonymous types in some web service responses).

Everything works fine authenticating to `/api/auth/credentials` but when there is a request to a secured web service the `GetSession()` extension method fails to get the `IAuthSession` from `ICacheClient` because is trying to deserialize to an interface (IAuthSession) and in Redis the JSON doesn't have type information because of the `JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo` setting so the serializer doesn't know which concrete type to use.﻿

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `CustomAuthUserSession` and have

```
JsConfig.Init(new Config {
    ExcludeTypeInfo = true
});
```

The solution is to enable it for the types that need it, in this case:

```
JsConfig<CustomAuthUserSession>.IncludeTypeInfo = true;
```

This is happening because ServiceStack lets you use and persist your own Custom UserSession it needs to persist that **__type** info with the payload to know what concrete type to dehydrate it into.

#### Supporting arbitrary responses

This is fairly rare as we only need to do this when a DTO can support holding arbitrary types, basically when using object, interfaces or abstract properties (i.e. we can't infer the type from the class definition). The only other place this exists in ServiceStack is in the MQ `Message<T>` type which allows persisting of any arbitrary body.

#### Use loose-typed data structures instead of anonymous types

By default, ServiceStack only adds the added **__type** info when it's required, although ideally you shouldn't be using anonymous types in service responses which requires deviating from the default configuration and the ["pit of success" development that ServiceStack encourages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369736/85785).

Using a loose-typed data structure like `Dictionary` or `List` is preferred for unstructured data as anonymous types basically prevent your DTO's from being deserializable, and prevents clients from having any idea of what the service ultimately returns - which will break anything that relies on your services from being statically inferable, e.g. XSDs/WSDLs/SOAP.