# ServiceStack AppHostHttpListenerBase Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, servicestack, functional-testing

I'm working through some Functional Tests on my app, and I think I'm getting pretty close. My problem is that when I run my first test, I get the error.

> unable to connect to the remote server.
>
> Expected: OK
>    But was:  0

I can confirm that if I put a breakpoint on the Assert, and then try to hit the `BaseUrl` in my browser, it is not found.

Here's my test.

```
[Test]
public void MyTestTest ()
{
    var client = new RestClient( ServiceTestAppHostBase.BaseUrl );
    // client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator( NUnitTestLoginName, NUnitTestLoginPassword );
    var request = new RestRequest( "/users/", Method.GET );
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    var response = client.Execute( request );

    // do assertions on the response object now
    Assert.That( response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo( HttpStatusCode.OK ) );
}
```

The `AppServerTestSetup` looks like this

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class AppServerTestSetup
{
    ServiceTestAppHostBase _appHost;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _appHost = new ServiceTestAppHostBase();
        _appHost.Init();
        _appHost.Start(ServiceTestAppHostBase.BaseUrl);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _appHost.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And the `ServiceTestAppHostBase` looks like this.

```
public class ServiceTestAppHostBase : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public const string BaseUrl = "http://localhost:8082/";
    public ServiceTestAppHostBase () : base( "OurApp.AppServer", typeof( UserServiceInterface ).Assembly ) { }

    public override void Configure ( Container container )
    {
        JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

        SetConfig( new EndpointHostConfig
        {
            MapExceptionToStatusCode = {
                { typeof( NotFoundException ), 404 }, // Map exception to 404 not found http response.
                { typeof( SystemAccountChangeException ), 405 } // Map exception to 405 method not allowed.
            }
        } );

        // Shared Container Registration
        AppHostContainerRegistrations.Register( container );

        // Setup the database
        var migrationRunner = container.Resolve<IMigrationRunner>();

        migrationRunner.CreateDatabase();
        migrationRunner.RunAll();
    }
}
```

note: I'm also using the `AppHostContainerRegistrations` in the main app, and it is working. I've also verified that it's being run in the test setup.

The `AppHostContainerRegistrations` (for reference) looks like this.

```
public class AppHostContainerRegistrations
{
    public static void Register(Container container)
    {
        // IOC Registration
        // Register base connection config
        var dbConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseConnection"];
        var databaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseName"];

        // Register Sqlserver DbProvider
        container.Register<IDbConnectionProvider>( containr => new DbConnectionProvider( dbConnection.ConnectionString, dbConnection.ProviderName ) );
        container.Register<IDbProvider>( containr => new DbProvider( containr.Resolve<IDbConnectionProvider>(), databaseName ) );

        // Register repositories
        container.RegisterAs<DatabaseVersionRepository, IDatabaseVersionRepository>();
        container.RegisterAs<UserRepository, IUserRepository>();
        container.RegisterAs<GroupRepository, IGroupRepository>();
        container.RegisterAs<DeviceRepository, IDeviceRepository>();
        container.RegisterAs<SecuritySettingsRepository, ISecuritySettingsRepository>();

        // Register services
        container.RegisterAs<UserService, IUserService>();
        container.RegisterAs<GroupService, IGroupService>();
        container.RegisterAs<SecuritySettingsService, ISecuritySettingsService>();

        // Register everything else
        container.RegisterAs<PasswordHasher, IPasswordHasher>();
        container.RegisterAs<MigrationRunner, IMigrationRunner>();

        container.Register( new UserModel { Id = new Guid( "6C83DDEC-5E58-4F28-BDE2-61EBF1B49691" ) } );

    }
}
```

The reason we're doing our Db setup like this is because we have a single connection string and db name in the App.Config, and we rely on Transforms during deployment to setup the database.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: ServiceStack auto-wires and registers it's own services, i.e. so if `UserService` is a ServiceStack `Service` remove the registration.

Comment: @mythz When I remove the registration, The SetUp throws a `NullReferenceException` on `_appHost.Init();`

Comment: and by "registration" I assume you're referring to `public ServiceTestAppHostBase () : base( "OurApp.AppServer", typeof( UserServiceInterface ).Assembly ) { }`

Comment: I'm referring to remove all Service Registrations, e.g: `container.RegisterAs<UserService, IUserService>()` if UserService is a ServiceStack Service - but I can't tell if it is here as we can't see the code.

Comment: @mythz Oh, no those are Services and Repositories that are contained within our PCL.

Comment: Our SS Service is called `UserServiceInterface`

Comment: @mythz is there any further information that I might need to provide?

Comment: Well the full HTTP Request/Response would be good (i.e. using Fiddler or WireShark). Any reason why you're not using [ServiceStack's Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client)?

Comment: @mythz I'm using RestSharp because that is what was decribed to me in another question. However, when changing to JsonServiceClient, I get `System.Net.WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8082`

Comment: Doesn't look like the HttpListener has started or has binded correctly. Try instead: `_appHost.Start("http://*:8082/");` also you should be in **Admin** node to run HttpListener.

Comment: @mythz admin mode? as in running VS as administrator?

Comment: Yep, VS as administrator mode, if that's where you're running the test. Usually only required for *reserved port ranges*, but it doesn't look like the HttpListener has started, so it may be the cause.

Comment: Turns out it was Administrator Mode. I'm going to try and find a work around so this isn't an issue in our automated builds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lengthy conversation with @mythz, it turns out that VS has to be run in Admin mode for the "AppHostHttpListenerBase" to run.

I also have to run Powershell as Admin when running ./build from the terminal.