# How to use ServiceStack DTO TranslateTo and PopulateWith?

Tags: c#, servicestack, dto

I am a `ServiceStack` newbie. I have a quite large .NET C# solution using `Cambium` ORM.

I am adding `ServiceStack` WebService project to my solution. I have followed [the guide](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice). Working correctly.

Now I want to add `UserService:Service` returning `User` DTO using `TranslateTo` or `PopulateWith` like written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368257/servicestack-new-service-side-by-side-asp-net-mvc-website/15369736#15369736).

```
[Route("/user")]
[Route("/user/{Id}")]
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}


public class UserService : Service
{
    private Users users = new Users();

    public UserResponse Get(User request)
    {
        return new UserResponse { Result = users.Single(request.Id).TranslateTo<User>() };
    }
}
```

However I am unable to locate these methods.

I am getting `<my_object_returned_from_database> does not contain a definition for 'TranslateTo'`.

I did cloned the `ServiceStack` repository and I cannot find any implementation of those methods in any extension.

What am I missing? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4):

For ServiceStack v3, which is the stable version currently available in [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/), `TranslateTo` and related methods are extension methods in the `ServiceStack.Common` namespace. Note that if you are cloning the GitHub repo, v3 is not the `master` branch. So adding a `using ServiceStack.Common` to your file should be sufficient to import the extension method.

ServiceStack v4, the `master` branch in GitHub, is a preview release. I think the TranslateTo extension method got renamed to `ConvertTo`.

Comment: Thanks @esker, did not notice the other branch :-( However I will need to stay with the `DynamicModel` implementation as the object returned from the database is `dynamic` so `TranslateTo` (probably iterating through properties) has nothing to copy.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the future me: although I was able to get the code compiled, it is not copying anything. It is because `Cambium` ORM returns `DynamicModel:Gemini`, that has no (DTO-related relevant) properties defined (see below to compare both `User` classes).

For example my `User` class in "data-access layer" looks like this:

```
public class User : DynamicModel, IUser
{
    public User() : base() { }

    public User(object dto)
        : base(dto)
    {
    }

    public Guid InternalId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator idata.User(User u)
    {
        idata.User result = new idata.User();
        u.CopyProperties(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

So at the end for DTO I used `DynamicModel` again and my DTO  `User` class is:

```
[Route("/user")]
[Route("/user/{Id}")]
public class User : DynamicModel
{
    public User(object dto)
        : base(dto)
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```