# ServiceStack Query String Mappings

Tags: routes, servicestack

I'm curious if it is possible to modify the servicesstack Route mapping rules. 
 I'd like non-query string parameters to go in one area of the model and the query string parameters to go into another.

Specifically, I have this Route:

```
[Route("/gis/services/{Folders*}/{ServiceName}/{ServiceType}/{LayerId}/query", HttpMethods.Get)]
public class Model : Envelope<Request>
{
}
```

And the Envelope is defined like this:

```
    public class Envelope<T>
    {
        public string Folders { get; set; }
        public string ServiceType { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public int LayerId { get; set; }
        public T Payload { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I map the query string parameters into the Payload and have everything else (Folders, ServiceType, ServiceName, LayerId) map as it normally would?

Answer (score 2):

Only the path info of the request are defined in ServiceStack Routes, all other properties can be populated by other Request Params like QueryString or Request Body.

#### Issues with your Routes

- You should also only be using WildCard mappings like `{folders*}` at the end of Routes to avoid ambiguity.
- Routes should match the **Exact Property Name** that's on the DTO, e.g. `{ServiceName}`
- For maximum interoperability your Request DTO should be flat and not have any complex type properties populated via QueryStrings for which there is no standard
- Your Request DTO is used to [define your Service Contract](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369736/85785) which we recommend against trying to DRY or hide behind inheritance
- Don't use the `Service` name for Request DTOs which is used for your Services implementation classes

Comment: I'm trying to be compatible with an existing API, so moving {Folders*} isn't an option.  But tip 3 & 4 together suggest a flat model with no inheritance is the best practice, with both path info and query strings mapping directly to properties on the model.  Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: @CoreyAlix yeah that would be preferred